What is the actual effect of a spitball?
In Backyard Baseball '97, one of the special pitches you can throw is a spitball. What does this pitch actually do? Is it just a different sort of off-speed pitch? The effect is less clear to me than, for example, the fireball.

According to Fandom,

The Spitball is the least drastic powerup pitch. It travels similar to a real-life knuckleball, and sprays spittle around the edges of the ball during its flight. There are theories that this pitch induces weaker contact than normal pitches, but none have been definitively proven yet. This pitch uses the least amount of juice out of all the powerup pitches.

According to Reddit,

Spitball : The ball is covered with spit, making it slightly move in another direction. In real baseball, this is an illegal pitch as it is part of the idea of ​​"doctoring the ball" where something liquid or of very small particles are applied to the ball to give it unnatural movement as it flies in the air.

